# Android JNI, how to load library with soname libxx.so.1.2.3

Tags: android, linux, java-native-interface

Need to use a shared lib for android from 3rd party, the lib's soname and file name are same, in format libxx.so.1.2.3, which is common on linux. I rename the lib file to libxx.so, and link libxx.so in libmyjni.so using ndk-build. In my java code, before calling the functions in libmyjni.so, I load them like this:

```
    System.load("/data/local/tmp/libxx.so.1.2.3");
    System.loadLibrary("myjni");
```

I have to manually copy libxx.so.1.2.3 to /data/local/tmp/. It works well in this way, after above loading, I can call functions in libmyjni.so.

In code "System.loadLibrary("myjni");", system always trying to get libxx.so.1.2.3 from somewhere. I want to know, in the real world, how could I copy libxx.so.1.2.3 to a specific location on android device during installation? so that I can System.load() it.

Or android has official way to install self made lib to /system/lib/?

If libxx.so.1.2.3 is in format libxx.so then I can use System.loadLibrary("xx") to load it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is finally what I did, keep the libxx.so.1.2.3 untouched and do all stuff in Java:

Put libxx.so.1.2.3 in android assets.
In MainApp.OnCreate(), copy the file to private file folder and load it from there:

```
    AssetManager am = applicationContext.getAssets(); 
    in = am.open(OPENSSL_SO_LIB_NAME); // source instream

    File privateStorageDir = applicationContext.getFilesDir();
    String libPath = privateStorageDir.getAbsolutePath();  // copy the lib to here ...

    System.load(libPath + "/" + SO_LIB_NAME);
```

Comment: Good one. I find the solution to my similar problem. Just your solution description is a little too concise to follow, and almost misleading, if someone is not familiar with copping files in the asset to the storage in the device.