# Android: Cannot load native library's dependency

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake

I am trying to load my native library(**libhello-jni.so**) with its dependency(**liblas.so**) in Android. but I always get this error

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1673): could not load library "liblas.so.2.0.0" needed by "libhello-jni.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:771): library "liblas.so.2.0.0" not found

I also use `System.loadlibrary("las")`  before load hello-jni library. 
By the way, I use android-cmake to generate libraries. 
The problems is I don't know how to export hello-jni 's dependency in cmake. Apparently, copy liblas.so to libs folder is not working. I think liblas.so is a link file to liblas.so.2.0.0  Also. here is my cmake file 
[image]

I been stuck at this for 2 weeks. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to change your make to link to `liblas.so`, or maybe `liblas.2.0.0.so`. If you need help with that, please publish your `Android.mk` file.

If you really need to use `liblas.so.2.0.0`, here the trick is described: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11434262/192373

Comment: well, this is not exactly what I want. I am using cmake not android ndk to build. besides, I got this error  `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)` when I  run app on android device.

Comment: If you use `cmake` to build your `libhello-jni.so`, you still have control over the link command. Maybe you should publish your cmake scripts, if you need help with them. Also, (Re: SIGSEGV) make sure that your build uses an Android-compatible toolchain.

Comment: I post my cmake file and I am using standalone toolchain with arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3 architecture.

Comment: I confess that I tried to <s>build</s> Cmake `liblas` for Android as an exercise, and failed miserably. If you are looking for a smooth path to work with Android, I recommend using `ndk-build` and static libs wherever possible.

Comment: I have built liblas successfully! I still use cmake and static libs to build. the error `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)` is because it did not found las file in android.